# Saved vlc stream skips

Tags: vlc-media-player, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I've scheduled vlc to save ts streams using cron.

cvlc https://somestream.ts --sout=file/ts:foo.mpg --run_time 4200

The resulting foo.mpg gets created and is playable. However, the resulting videos skips and is incomplete. I'm doing this on a Pi Model B+ too. Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to me trying to capture a .m3u8. M3u8s are just text files for playlists containing actual links. Thus, vlc would miss some data causing the choppiness. I solved this by using ffmpeg and everything works great.